# Status code 400 when trying to use the petstore3 API

Tags: api-testing

I am experimenting with API testing but I am stuck almost at the beginning. Please tell me maybe I am doing something wrong?

1. On the [petstore3.swagger.io](http://petstore3.swagger.io) web-page I press Authorize button and enter the value for the api_key.
2. In Fiddler - Composer I choose POST method and https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet address.
3. In Header I set api_key value equal to the one I entered in step 1.
4. In Body I copy-paste JSON from the example at petstore3.swagger.io

My request in a raw form looks ok:

```
POST https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/pet HTTP/1.1
User-Agent:Fiddler Everywhere
Host:petstore3.swagger.io
Content-Length:215
api_key:20202020

{
  "id": 11,
  "name": "doggie2",
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dogs"
  },
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

but when I execute it I get the 400 Bad Request error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 07 Sep 2020 21:01:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
Server: Jetty(9.4.9.v20180320)
```

Comment: How about trying adding `content-type: application/json` ?

Comment: Try using postman, it's different enough to probably help you find the issue

Comment: Also, the server returns an explanation in body on error, something like `{ "code": 400,
    "message": "Input error: The input body..." }`. That could also help you. But it seems it's really the missing header Content-Type in this case.

Comment: Can you pass `accept --> application/xml` in the header. The response I am getting is in xml format and also the curl command generated swagger has the same.